# StateNotifierProvider only wach changes once

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

In my last question about [StateNotifierProvider not updating state using HookWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68566388/statenotifierprovider-not-updating-state) my issue as calculating two `TextFormField` has been solved, now instead of using `HookWidget` i try to implement that with `ConsumerWidget`. i migrated my last code to:

```dart
class CalculateTextFormField extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,ScopedReader watch) {
    final cashCounterProvider = watch(cashProvider);
    final TextEditingController _count = TextEditingController();
    final TextEditingController _cash = TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('${cashCounterProvider.count + cashCounterProvider.cash}'),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _count,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (value) =>
                  context.read(cashProvider.notifier).setCount(int.tryParse(value) ?? 0),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _cash,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (value) =>
                  context.read(cashProvider.notifier).setCash(int.tryParse(value) ?? 0),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final cashProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CashCounter, CashCounterData>((ref) => CashCounter());

class CashCounter extends StateNotifier<CashCounterData> {
  CashCounter() : super(_initialData);

  static const _initialData = CashCounterData(0, 0);

  void setCount(int value){
    state = CashCounterData(value, state.cash);
  }

  void setCash(value){
    state = CashCounterData(state.count, value);
  }

  int get count => state.count;
  int get cash => state.cash;
}

class CashCounterData {
  final int count;
  final int cash;

  const CashCounterData(this.count, this.cash);
}
```

here i defined `cashCounterProvider` and when i try to enter value into `TextFormField` i can't enter multiple value and this line as

```dart
Text('${cashCounterProvider.count + cashCounterProvider.cash}'),
```

does work once. i try to implemeting a simple calculator on multiple entering value into inputs

Comment: Writing up an answer now, but why not just use your hooks implementation? Why change what works?

Comment: @AlexHartford as `riverpod` deosn't have good documentation :lol: i'm trying to make simple project to learn more about it, thanks so much as answer to my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers in Flutter need to be declared outside the build method unless using [hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks). Whenever you type into one of your TextFields, the widget is being rebuilt, which causes your controller to be reassigned.

If using hooks, the following is fine:

```dart
class CalculatableTextFormField extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cashCounterProvider = useProvider(cashProvider);
    final TextEditingController _count = useTextEditingController();
    final TextEditingController _cash = useTextEditingController();
    ...
```

Otherwise, declare controllers outside the build method:

```dart
class CalculatableTextFormField extends ConsumerWidget {
  final TextEditingController _count = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _cash = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final cashCounterProvider = watch(cashProvider);
    ...
```

One of my favorite benefits of hooks is not having to handle disposal logic on your own. [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) is an example of handling the lifecycle of a TextEditingController. After reading that, take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/rrousselGit/flutter_hooks/blob/master/packages/flutter_hooks/lib/src/text_controller.dart#L58) for `useTextEditingController`. That should help make sense of how things are working.

Comment: typing multiple into inputs solved, thanks so much, but this line`Text('${cashCounterProvider.count + cashCounterProvider.cash}'),` is not sum of two input values and show only one of input values

Comment: could you please help me how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: so, what's problem and how can i resolve? i don't understand me. could you clarify your meant?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Have you tried restarting the app?

Comment: i just found what was problem, thanks so much

Comment: could you help me on this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68850044/1830228