# Flutter update state of multiple nested class data using Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

after searching on many tutorial i can't update nested class data with this implementation, here i have a `OrderStructure` with a two field such as `title` and list of `products` which this `product` is another list named `services` which i defined on parent class

first of all when user click on button i save `title` and empty `product`'s service

```dart
void increment(int productId, int serviceId, int serviceCost) {
  final found = state.products.indexWhere((product) => product.id == productId);
  if (found < 0) {
    final List<SelectedProductServices> _s = [];
    _s.add(SelectedProductServices(serviceId, 1, serviceCost));
    state = OrderStructure(
      state.title
      [...state.products, SelectedProducts(productId, _s)],
    );
  }
```

now when `found` is equal or bigger than `0`, i should find `product` with passed `productId` and inside this search i should find `service`, if it saved before `cost` should be increment`otherwise it should insert new data in`products`

this is my code which i can't complete that and that has error and another problem is incrementing `count`

```dart
state = OrderStructure(state.title, [
  ...state.products,
  for (final product in state.products)
    if (product.id == productId)
      for (final service in product.services)
        if (service.id == serviceId)
          SelectedProducts(
              state.products, [...service, SelectedProductServices(service.id, service.count+1, service.cost)])
        else
          ...state.products
]);
```

data classes structure:

```dart
class OrderStructure {
  final String title;
  final List<SelectedProducts> products;

  const OrderStructure(this.title,this.products);
}

class SelectedProducts {
  final int id;
  final List<SelectedProductServices> services;

  SelectedProducts(this.id, this.services);
}

class SelectedProductServices {
  final int id;
  final int count;
  final int cost;

  const SelectedProductServices(this.id, this.count, this.cost);
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @DelphiX yeah i found it, please email me if i can help you. I am traveling now, pishguy[at @]gmail.com